# Bean instantiation via factory method failed

Tags: spring-boot

I am getting below error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fileStorageServiceBean' defined in com.primesolutions.fileupload.settings.FileStorageProperties: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.primesolutions.fileupload.service.FileStorageService]: Factory method 'fileStorageServiceBean' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "file")
public class FileStorageProperties {

    private String uploadDir;

    @Bean
    public FileStorageService fileStorageServiceBean() throws Exception{
        return new FileOnDiskStorageService();  // some random name; don't exist
    }

    public String getUploadDir() {
        return uploadDir;
    }

    public void setUploadDir(String uploadDir) {
        this.uploadDir = uploadDir;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it could be solved by some "search" on the error. A search  for `java.lang.StackOverflowError` should give enough information to solve the question.

Answer (score 2):

Your method:

```
public FileStorageService fileStorageServiceBean() throws Exception{
    return fileStorageServiceBean();
}
```

Is a [recursive](https://www.google.com/search?q=recursion) function. Which causes the stackOverflowError.

Comment: Hi willem after removing the above method getting following error ......Description:

Field fileStorageService in com.primesolutions.fileupload.controller.FileController required a bean of type 'com.primesolutions.fileupload.service.FileStorageService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
 - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.primesolutions.fileupload.service.FileStorageService' in your configuration.

Comment: Add the `@Service` annotation above your `FileStorageService` class

Answer (score 0):

You get a `java.lang.StackOverflowError` because the method fileStorageServiceBean() is calling itself and that will result in an infinite loop. That code part can never end in this situation.

It could/should be something like:

```
@Bean
public FileStorageService fileStorageServiceBean() throws Exception{
    return new FileOnDiskStorageService();  // some random name; don't exist
}
```

If you use a good IDE it will warn you about this. It's a good advice to always use a good IDE for Java and read the warnings. Also installing the plugins like SonarQube, Findbugs is really helpful to prevent for code issues.

Also the errors stacktrace will give a line number and some info where in the code the error occurs.